# How can I find all places a given member function or ctor is called in g++ code?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to find all places in a large and old code base where certain constructors or functions are called.  Specifically, these are certain constructors and member functions in the `std::string` class (that is, `basic_string<char>`).  For example, suppose there is a line of code:

```
std::string foo(fiddle->faddle(k, 9).snark);
```

In this example, it is not obvious looking at this that `snark` may be a `char *`, which is what I'm interested in.

**Attempts To Solve This So Far**

I've looked into some of the dump features of gcc, and generated some of them, but I haven't been able to find any that tell me that the given line of code will generate a call to the `string` constructor taking a `const char *`.  I've also compiled some code with -s to save the generated equivalent assembly code.  But this suffers from two things: the function names are "mangled," so it's impossible to know what is being called in C++ terms; and there are no line numbers of any sort, so even finding the equivalent place in the source file would be tough.

**Motivation and Background**

In my project, we're porting a large, old code base from HP-UX (and their aCC C++ compiler) to RedHat Linux and gcc/g++ v.4.8.5.  The HP tool chain allowed one to initialize a `string` with a `NULL` pointer, treating it as an empty string.  The Gnu tools' generated code fails with some flavor of a null dereference error.  So we need to find all of the potential cases of this, and remedy them.  (For example, by adding code to check for `NULL` and using a pointer to a `""` string instead.)

So if anyone out there has had to deal with the base problem and can offer other suggestions, those, too, would be welcomed.

Comment: Work out the mangled name for the function you are trying to look for

Comment: Maybe you could do a global search-and-replace to change `std::string` and `string` to some class of your own that will then log a message when that particular constructor is called

Comment: Rename the function/change the constructor's parameters, recompile everything, and have the compiler find it for you.

Comment: Can you create a subclass of string and override the constructor, then #define your class as string?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using static analysis?

Clang has one called clang analyzer that is extensible.

You can write a custom plugin that checks for this particular behavior by implementing  a clang ast visitor that looks for string variable declarations and checks for setting it to null.

There is a manual for that [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html).

See also:  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-clang-plugins/blob/master/analyzer/DanglingDelegateFactFinder.cpp

Answer (score 0):

First I'd create a header like this:

```
#include <string>

class dbg_string : public std::string {
public:
    using std::string::string;
    dbg_string(const char*) = delete;
};

#define string dbg_string
```

Then modify your makefile and add "-include dbg_string.h" to cflags to force include on each source file without modification.

You could also check how is NULL defined on your platform and add specific overload for it (eg. dbg_string(int)).

Comment: Thats super hacky, but very interesting and creative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) and its CQLinq a powerful code query language to detect where some contructors/methods/fields/types are used.

```
from m in Methods where m.IsUsing ("CClassView.CClassView()") select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```